# Access an array that's on a 3rd dimension with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a sub array out of a larger array object.

I am able to access the 2nd level using the code below:

```
 var value = $(this).val(); 
 var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
            alert(id + "-" + value); // outputs OK the id and value veriables are good EG "I17-SATISFACTORY"
            console.log(autoPop[id]); // gives me the array from I17
            console.log(autoPop[id][value]); // says undefined
```

Here is the array:

```
{
"I34": [
    {
        "Y": [{
                "I35": "N/A",
                "I39": "Y",
                "I43": "Y"
            }],
        "LIM": [{
                "I35": "N/A",
                "I36": "N/A"
            }]
    }
], 
"I4": [
    {
        "0": [{
                "I36": "N/A"
            }],
        "1": [{
                "I7": "TEST OK ",
                "I8": "N/A"

            }]
    }
],
    "I17": [
    {
        "SATISFACTORY": [{
                "I7": "test ok 2",
                "I37": "N/A",
                "I38": "N/A",
                "I39": "Y",
                "I43": "Y"
            }],
        "UNSATISFACTORY": [{
                "I7": "TEST OK ",
                "I8": "N/A"

            }]
    }
]
}
```

I've been trying with dot notation and brackets. I found that you need to use brackets with variable

Once i can access the array i then need to loop through the array and use jQuery to update the values of fields etc.

Hopefully i'm on the right track and someone can work out what i'm doing wrong!

Thanks 
Chris

**EDIT**
For clarification: 
The value i would like to get is, or an object array with:

```
[{
            "I7": "test ok 2",
            "I37": "N/A",
            "I38": "N/A",
            "I39": "Y",
            "I43": "Y"
        }]
```

Comment: which value you want from the array?

Comment: [{
                "I7": "test ok 2",
                "I37": "N/A",
                "I38": "N/A",
                "I39": "Y",
                "I43": "Y"
            }]

Comment: Each time you have an array with a single object in it (which seems a bit pointless, but well..), so you should access it with an extra `[0]`: `autoPop[id][0][value]`

Answer (score 0):

Because there is an object in every level, you always need to first get that object, using `[0]`, then, look for what you want:

```js
var arr = {
  "I34": [{
    "Y": [{
      "I35": "N/A",
      "I39": "Y",
      "I43": "Y"
    }],
    "LIM": [{
      "I35": "N/A",
      "I36": "N/A"
    }]
  }],
  "I4": [{
    "0": [{
      "I36": "N/A"
    }],
    "1": [{
      "I7": "TEST OK ",
      "I8": "N/A"

    }]
  }],
  "I17": [{
    "SATISFACTORY": [{
      "I7": "test ok 2",
      "I37": "N/A",
      "I38": "N/A",
      "I39": "Y",
      "I43": "Y"
    }],
    "UNSATISFACTORY": [{
      "I7": "TEST OK ",
      "I8": "N/A"

    }]
  }]
}

console.log(arr["I17"]);
console.log(arr["I17"][0]["SATISFACTORY"]);
console.log(arr["I17"][0]["SATISFACTORY"][0]["I7"]);
```